# Flexslider and mousewhell speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I want to use flexslider with mousewheel here is the my example

```
        $('#slider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            mousewheel: true,
            direction: "vertical",
            slideshow: false
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VC4L3/

it's working but too fast. I'm using magic mouse by the way I'm trying touchpad too when I scroll down it's moving 2,3 sliders. I need each scrol down move 1 slide. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a simple solution for this so i have changed the source code of the flexslider, to disable scroll once the animation is started, here is what i did:

1. change bind for mousewheel to be like this.

   ```
   slider.bind('mousewheel', function (event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) { 
   if (!slider.startedMouseWheel) {
       slider.startedMouseWheel = true;
       event.preventDefault();
       var target = (delta < 0) ? slider.getTarget('next') : slider.getTarget('prev');
       slider.flexAnimate(target, slider.vars.pauseOnAction);
   }
   ```

   });
2. find call of the vars after function

and insert this code before it:

```
slider.startedMouseWheel = false;
```

to have

```
slider.startedMouseWheel = false;   
slider.vars.after(slider); //This is call of the vars after function
```

this way you will disable triggering new events on mouse scroll until animation is finnished.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `animationSpeed` into the flexslider.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/VC4L3/1/

```
 $('#slider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            mousewheel: true,
            direction: "vertical",
            slideshow: false,               
            animationSpeed: 4000,
        });
```

Comment: Sorry but it's not working. Still when I scroll down it's jumping end of slider but this time slowly. I want to each scroll down go to next slide.